# Symfony JsonResponse with Location header results in 302

Tags: php, rest, symfony, jsonresponse

I am trying to return a json response which also has a location header. Before the request was returning this

```
return new Response('', Response::HTTP_CREATED, ['Location' => $url]);
```

I need to add an ID as part of the request body so I decided to just convert it to JsonResponse

```
 return new JsonResponse(['createdId' => $createdId], Response::HTTP_CREATED, ['Location' => $url]);
```

To my surprise instead of a 201 code it returns 302. I can add the url to the json body and let front-end handle the redirect, but there should be a better way?

Comment: _"but there should be a better way?"_ - no; you _either_ redirect, _or_ you send data back to the client. Both at the same time, makes little sense. (A 3xx response is allowed to be accompanied by a response body - but that has only "informal" character then, resp. is supposed to be alternative content for clients you are not able to or not allowed to follow automatic redirects. You should not use it to transport any _essential_ data in such a case.)

Comment: Mmmh. I just tried with a blank Symfony project, and there is no status code conversion. I send back `new JsonResponse(['abc' => 'def'], Response::HTTP_CREATED, ['Location' => 'https://www.example.com/abc'])`, and I get a 201 status code as expected. https://cln.sh/3ZLLVvlK94gXMmR7ZXKL

Comment: Just for the record, a 201 response **can** include a `Location` header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location. But I'm afraid that with the above details, the problem you state is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would check what the **url** and **createdId** variables contain before sending. Their content may influence the result.